# Smart way of not getting N+1 while querying has_many relationship in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select-n-plus-1

I have a `Movie` model and a `MovieStream` model. The relation is Movie `has_many` MediaType (and MediaType `belongs_to` Movie).

MediaType has two attribues "url_broken" (true/false) and "dvd" (true/false).

In my view I have:

```
Movie.all.includes(:movie_item).each do |movie|
  render partial: 'movie_item'
end
```

and in `movie_item`-partial I have (simplified):

```
<h1><%= movie.title %></h1>

<% if movie.media_types.where(:url_broken => false).blank? %>
  No media types exist
<% else %>
<h2>Streams</h2>
<% streams = movie.media_types.where(:dvd => false).each do |media_type| %>
  * <%= media_type.name %>
<% end %>

<h2>Dvd's</h2>
<% dvds = movie.media_types.where(:dvd => true).each do |media_type| %>
  * <%= media_type.name %>
<% end %>
```

This (obviously) causes N+1 queries but I cannot see any way around it. Is it possible, in some way, to query the view-query in a way that I can get the `streams` and `dvds` at the same time?

Like:

```
Movie.all.join_stream_something.each do |movie, streams, dvds|
render partial: 'movie_item', :locals => { :movie => movie, :streams => streams, :dvds => dvds}
end
```

to not have N+1?
end

Answer (score 1):

you can define a scoped `has_many`(s) in the movie class

```rb
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :valid_url_media_types, -> { where(url_broken: false) }, class_name: "MediaType"
  has_many :not_dvd_media_types, -> { where(dvd: false) }, class_name: "MediaType"
  has_many :dvd_media_types, -> { where(dvd: true) }, class_name: "MediaType"
end
```

then in your view

```
Movie.all.includes(:valid_url_media_types, :not_dvd_media_types, :dvd_media_types).each do |movie|
  render partial: 'movie_item', movie: movie
end
```

your partial:

```
<h1><%= movie.title %></h1>

<% if movie.valid_url_media_types.blank? %>
  No media types exist
<% else %>
<h2>Streams</h2>
<% streams = movie.not_dvd_media_types.each do |media_type| %>
  * <%= media_type.name %>
<% end %>

<h2>Dvd's</h2>
<% dvds = movie.dvd_media_types.each do |media_type| %>
  * <%= media_type.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: HOW can I have missed this!? This is exactly what I needed. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to use an `.includes`

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes

```
Movie.includes(:media_type).all.each do |movie|
  render partial: 'movie_item', :locals => { :movie => movie }
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately no (I already do actually, should have included that in my simplified description). The .where inside the loop causes sql calls, and if I am not mistaken a .where call always do.